# Android SET Visibility GONE but still VISIBLE

Tags: android, visibility, space, visible

my first time asking here sorry if i break any rules

So my question is, how can i make a certain layout to not take up any space ( so i can still click and touch what ever behind it ), but still visible ?

MY CASE :
i'm developing an app where you can create an image, trhough manipulating and image and an edittext on top of it ( for overlapping image combination ).
Wheren the edittext doesnt take space, i can still touch and manipulate the image below it, but when i type the edittext to a full line, i cant manipulate the image behind it. I've already make a button to switch between text/image editing ( disable image onclick/setfocusable false editext )

Any help appreciated

EDIT

```
public void setTextEdit()
{
    textToolsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageToolsLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    textSablon.setFocusable(true);
    textSablon.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    textSablon.setClickable(true);
    textSablon.requestFocus();
    textSablon.setCursorVisible(true);
    textSablon.setEnabled(true);

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(fullSablonLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

    imgSablon.setEditable(false);
}

public void setImageEdit()
{
    imageToolsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textToolsLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    textSablon.setFocusable(false);
    textSablon.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    textSablon.setClickable(false);
    textSablon.setCursorVisible(false);
    textSablon.setEnabled(false);
    textSablon.setOnTouchListener(null);
    imgSablon.setEditable(true);
}
```

Those are the button's on click function, imgSablon is the imageview UNDER the edittext, and textSablon in ONTOP of the imageview.

again, i wanted the edittext to STILL BE VISIBLE, but doesnt take space so i can still touch the imageview UNDER it.

is it possible ?

ANOTHER ANALOGY:
say there is a BUTTON, on top on another BUTTON.
normaly when you click the visible BUTTON, you click the top one.
i wanted the top one to still be VISIBLE, but it ignores input, so when i try to click, the BOTTOM BUTTON gets clicked instead

i hope this helps

Comment: could be helpful some sample code, you have tried

Comment: edited, those are still experimental code

Comment: @MaxPinto help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `EditText` with `onTouchEvent` overridden. You can control whether you can touch the view by toggling some boolean `touch`.

```
RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
parent.addView(new EditText(this){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return touch;
    }
});
```

Comment: but then how to toggle when i really want to edit my edittext

Comment: not saying that this is wrong, but is there a more direct solution ? like setVisibility(GONE), but still render whatever in it

Comment: There's no more direct solution afaik. As I said in the answer, change the toggle variable to make the view touchable or not.